# instanceof not working when exception raised from a shared node module?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, node-modules

Have a javascript application which includes a shared module and a main module. Both modules include the same version of `puppeteer`. A method in the shared module is responsible for creating the browser and handing off the `page` instance to my main module to interact with it. This works fine, but I'm running into an issue trying to capture a TimeoutError in the main module.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
try { 
   await page.waitForXPath("//")
} catch (error) { 
if (error instanceof TimeoutError) { 
   continue;
} else { 
   throw error;
}
```

However, the `error instanceof TimeoutError` never returns true.

Here is a minimal reproducible example.

**Shared package.json**

```
{
  "name": "shared",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^20.7.2"
  }
}
```

**Shared main.js**

```
import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer";

export function throwError() {
  throw new puppeteer.TimeoutError("Timeout from shared");
}
```

**Main package.json**

```
{
  "name": "main",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "puppeteer": "^20.7.2",
    "shared": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

**Main main.js**

```
import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import * as shared from "shared";

try {
  shared.throwError();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error instanceof puppeteer.TimeoutError);
}
```

I would expect this to print `True`, but it does not. I suspect its because the `puppeteer` imported by the main module is not the same `puppeteer` imported by the shared module, even though they are the same version.

To run this locally, I've run `npm link` in `shared` project and then `npm link shared` in the main project.

If I remove the puppeteer* modules from both the main/node_modules and main/node_modules/shared/node_modules directories and install it in the same directory as main and shared folders, the example works as expected since the same puppeteer modules are resolved for both.

Comment: I get `ERROR TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object` when doing `if(e instanceof puppeteer.TimeoutError)`, that may be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that it's a bug from **puppeteer** itself, well described in this Github issue : https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/7545

You can update to the latest version of **puppeteer**, to see if it's fixed
or
You can use the following as a workaround (string comparison on the error's name)

[image: diff between OP's code and a workaround]